# how to center a label on a pane in javafx

Tags: java, layout, javafx, pane

I'd like to set results to the centre of `Pane`.

```
Label results = new Label("You win");
Pane pane = new Pane();
pane.getChildren().add(results);
```

I've tried both lines of code below and neither works.

```
results.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
results.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.CENTER);
```

Btw, I know how to get this centered with `StackPane` and `GridPane` but in this case I need to use a plain `Pane`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Pane` does not support centering a child. Therefore it has to be done manually, i.e. the `layoutX` and `layoutY` positions have to be calculated "manually".

You can achieve this through binding:

```
results.layoutXProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty().subtract(results.widthProperty()).divide(2));
// procede accordingly with layoutY / height
```

Answer (score -1):

I was boring with binding, so i made some simple. My "MessageBox" is always at center since then. Center Pane to AnchorPane. May work with other Controls and Containers, i didn't try.

```
double w = (anchorpane.getWidth()/2)-(panel.getWidth()/2);
double h = (anchorpane.getHeight()/2)-(panel.getHeight()/2);
panel.setLayoutX(w); panel.setLayoutY(h);
```